# Android wear settings activity

Tags: android, wear-os

What is the right design pattern for settings on android wear from user interface point of view? I mean: on a phone there is a preference activity/fragment and so on and on wear? I didn't find anything in android wear docs with the exception of watchfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the advice for watch faces. For simple settings, you can have a custom activity that will run directly on the wearable. For more complex settings, you should create a settings activity on the phone side, that will sync the settings using Data API.

Answer (score 3):

I found WearPreferenceActivity by Denley Bihari to suffice for small amount of Preferences on the device side.

https://github.com/denley